# Building Boost on Mac OS M1 chipset

Tags: boost, g++, clang, arm64

I tried almost a hundred things to make this works but nothing seems to be working.
I recently acquire a Mac book pro M1 MAX (so arm64 architecture), system provided by default with clang g++.

I wanted to install boost library. Using homebrew the 1.80 version was installed but I need to work on a project with the 1.65.1 version (I tried compiling my project with 1.80 version and tons of undefined symbols and errors were raised from boost library even if I have all of them, so I'm guessing I need to install the exact same version required)

so I decided to build and compile boost by myself following the boost guide
[https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html/)

Following section 5.1 I tried to use the bootstrap script and this one fails using Darwin toolset. (apparently some Clang warning caused error). I resolve then by changing the boost source code like  this :
https://github.com/boostorg/build/commit/48e9017139dd94446633480661e5447c7e0d8b1b

But there's still lot of issues during the compilation

[image: bootstrap_errors]

I don't know what to do to be able to compile with clang, I don't even know if this will be compiled for arm64 architecture.

anyway I install gcc compiler and tried with gcc toolset.

`./bootstrap --with-toolset=gcc`

The bootstraps works but then running the b2 script cause a segmentation fault instantly and on every commands I tried (even the --help options raised an exception...).

Why is building boost so complicated on arm chipset ?
What can I do to build boost (either clang or gcc, arm or cross compiled universal library) ?
I'm desperate at this point.

Thanks for the help.

I tried everything
with clang (darwin)

with gcc

with options to add arm64 as architecture

changing the source code of boost to fix

Answer (score 2):

You almost got a working Boost.

> anyway I install gcc compiler and tried with gcc toolset.
> `./bootstrap --with-toolset=gcc`
> The bootstraps works but then running the b2 script cause a segmentation fault instantly and on every commands I tried (even the --help options raised an exception...).

This was caused by a memory corruption bug in b2 due to a line of sloppy C code that invoked undefined behavior. Since the code was executed during initialization, it completely broke b2. But it only happens when on the ARM64 Darwin ABI, and only when GCC is used, and otherwise it's hidden on most platforms, so it was never identified.

Back in February 2023, I've [debugged the issue](https://github.com/bfgroup/b2/issues/152#issuecomment-1436602829) and submitted [a patch to b2](https://github.com/bfgroup/b2/pull/214) and [now the fix has been included in b2 v4.9.4 and later versions](https://github.com/bfgroup/b2/commit/2dfa491ea887ddae516dd231278f40b8436ecf64).

> Why is building boost so complicated on arm chipset ?

Lack of testing, since it's a new platform.

> What can I do to build boost (either clang or gcc, arm or cross compiled universal library) ? I'm desperate at this point.

Please upgrade your b2 to the latest version (currently 4.9.6) and try again.